# How to download a url whith libcurl and donot unzip it

Tags: libcurl

By default, libcurl will download a url, if the url is gzipped (content-type: gzip), libcurl will unzip it,

Is it possible that let libcurl do not unzip it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, libcurl will not by default decompress a response body that is sent compressed. It would only do that automatically if you set [CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html) accordingly.

The default behavior by libcurl is to deliver the data to the application exactly and unmodified, as it was sent by the server.